# How to collapse rows with the same information in R package GT

Tags: html, r, dplyr, gt

I have a data frame that has an unique identifier, some summary statistics, and then individualized comments. The table looks something like this:

```
Name    Mean    Median    Comment 
Boat    7       5          Can float.
Boat    7       5          Has been known to sink.
Boat    7       5          Once in a lifetime experience.
Car     4       8          Has wheels
Car     4       8          Can't float.
```

I want to visualize (in an html format) this table using the package GT, in a way that the comments come off as in a pagebreak, one after another if the prior 3 columns (Name, Mean, and Median) are identical.

```
Name    Mean    Median    Comment 
Boat    7       5          Can float.
                           Has been known to sink.
                           Once in a lifetime experience.
Car     4       8          Has wheels
                           Can't float.
```

I would like the end results to look something like the collapse_rows function from other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of a better solution, here is a workaround:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), .by = c(Name, Mean, Median)) %>%
  mutate(across(c(Name, Mean, Median), ~ifelse(row == 1, ., ""))) %>%
  gt()
```

[image: table]

Comment: This works, thanks.
I added a line  `dplyr::select( -row)`  at the end to remove the row column.